# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined in angularjs 6

Tags: html, angular

I am getting "Cannot read property '0' of undefined".

This is my HTML code

```html
<!-- ... -->
<img src="{{hit._source.productPhoto[0].docURL}}">
```

This is my JSON data:

```json
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "costbo",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "product-e89120f49a734cc7bc7562d96e2de77b",
    "_score": 3.7523928,
    "_source": {
      "productOriginalPrice": 0,
      "productSalePrice": 0,
      "productPhoto": [
        {
          "docLURL": "",
          "docType": "service1-Asdx89",
          "docSURL": "",
          "name": "photo",
          "docURL": "https://storage.googleapis.com/bo3151920215/business/d1bef58035ac4a19bde4e2646937a71c/product/e89120f49a734cc7bc7562d96e2de77b/service1-Asdx89.jpeg",
          "docMURL": ""
        }
      ],
      ...
    }
]
```

Other parameters are working, however I'm only getting the error on the line with the binding curly brackets.

Comment: Hello, M.venkateshwaran! Welcome to StackOverflow! Although I've done it for you, please consider indenting your code with 4 spaces. Secondly, please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question. Lastly, please insert the parent's HTML in your first snippet.

Comment: it appears you are using `*ngFor` on `hits` and using `hit` for a single object. Please check if all the objects in array have the `productPhoto` array.

Comment: Check out this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234

Answer (score 0):

Check your json again. It looks like `productPhoto` is missing. The json you shared is completely fine. It will be better if you can share your entire json.

Comment: `productPhoto` --> It's available!

Comment: I have tired like below but still error .   <img src="{{hit._source.productPhoto[0]?.docURL}}">

Comment: Then you must be able to access by `{{hit._source.productPhoto[0].docURL}}`

Comment: Just check your entire for loop  
`<div *ngFor="let hit of hits">
    <img src={{hit._source.productPhoto[0].docURL}}/>
  </div>`

Answer (score 0):

The `hits` is an array so you have to use index position to iterate over an array

Below line will work for you in which have used an index position as `0`

```
hits[0]._source.productPhoto[0].docURL;
```

But how I would do this:

Here is [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-potlkg) Example to display all images with the `forLoop`

Comment: If still not then provide the stackblitz example with your code

Comment: @venkateshwaran if the posted answers helps you to solve your problem then accept the answer